# How to calculate the differential of the following stochastic integral?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $$Y_t=\int_t^T f(t,s)\ \mathsf  dW_s$$ I want to compute $\mathsf dY_t$. This suggests me to consider how to find $\mathsf dY_t$ for $$Y_t=\int_t^T f(t,s)\ \mathsf dW_s$$ or $$Y_t=\int_t^T g(t,s)\ \mathsf ds,$$ if $g(t,s)$ is stochastic. Are there any general rule to compute these kinds of differential?

Comment: This is not so innocent as it seems. What is $dY_t$ for $Y_t = \int_t^T f(s) dW_s$? You might guess that this is $-f(s) dW_s$, but there is problem. The fact is that, traditionally, the stochastic differential is defined for so-called Ito processes, which are adapted by definition. The process $Y$ is not adapted. Therefore, no differential (in the classical sense).

So the question you need to answer first is this: What is $dY_t$ for a non-adapted process $Y$?

Comment: I get what you mean, but it is not. To be precise, $f(t,s)$ should be deterministic. $g(t,s)$ is stochastic and adapted.